# website not accessible after idling some time running nginx and kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

My website is not accessible from the browser for a few minutes after idling or not accessing it like 30 minutes or more. I would have to reload the page for how many times to view the page and I am not sure which to debug.

the stack I am running is a Golang app behind nginx that runs on kubernetes ingress. here is part of my nginx.conf.

```
            daemon off;

            worker_processes 2;
            pid /run/nginx.pid;

            worker_rlimit_nofile 523264;
            events {
                multi_accept        on;
                worker_connections  16384;
                use                 epoll; 
            }

            http {
                real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For;
                set_real_ip_from    0.0.0.0/0;
                real_ip_recursive   on;

                geoip_country       /etc/nginx/GeoIP.dat;
                geoip_city          /etc/nginx/GeoLiteCity.dat;
                geoip_proxy_recursive on;
                # lua section to return proper error codes when custom pages are used
                lua_package_path '.?.lua;./etc/nginx/lua/?.lua;/etc/nginx/lua/vendor/lua-resty-http/lib/?.lua;';
                init_by_lua_block {
                    require("error_page")
                }

                sendfile            on;
                aio                 threads;
                tcp_nopush          on;
                tcp_nodelay         on;
                log_subrequest      on;

                reset_timedout_connection on;

                keepalive_timeout 75s;

                client_header_buffer_size       1k;
                large_client_header_buffers     4 8k;

                types_hash_max_size             2048;
                server_names_hash_max_size      512;
                server_names_hash_bucket_size   64;
                map_hash_bucket_size            64;

                include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                default_type text/html;
                gzip on;
                gzip_comp_level 5;
                gzip_http_version 1.1;
                gzip_min_length 256;
                gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/css text/plain text/x-component;    
                gzip_proxied any;

                server_tokens on;   

                log_format upstreaminfo '$remote_addr - '
                    '[$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for] - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                    '$request_length $request_time [$proxy_upstream_name] $upstream_addr $upstream_response_length $upstream_response_time $upstream_status';

                map $request_uri $loggable {
                    default 1;
                }

                access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreaminfo if=$loggable;
                error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;

                resolver 10.131.240.10 valid=30s;

                # Retain the default nginx handling of requests without a "Connection" header
                map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
                    default          upgrade;
                    ''               close;
                }

                # trust http_x_forwarded_proto headers correctly indicate ssl offloading
                map $http_x_forwarded_proto $pass_access_scheme {
                    default          $http_x_forwarded_proto;
                    ''               $scheme;
                }

                map $http_x_forwarded_port $pass_server_port {
                default           $http_x_forwarded_port;
                ''                $server_port;
                }

                # map port 442 to 443 for header X-Forwarded-Port
                map $pass_server_port $pass_port {
                    442              443;
                    default          $pass_server_port;
                }

                # Map a response error watching the header Content-Type
                map $http_accept $httpAccept {
                    default          html;
                    application/json json;
                    application/xml  xml;
                    text/plain       text;
                }

                map $httpAccept $httpReturnType {
                    default          text/html;
                    json             application/json;
                    xml              application/xml;
                    text             text/plain;
                }

                server_name_in_redirect off;
                port_in_redirect        off;

                ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

                # turn on session caching to drastically improve performance
                ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
                ssl_session_timeout 10m;

                # allow configuring ssl session tickets
                ssl_session_tickets on;

                # slightly reduce the time-to-first-byte
                ssl_buffer_size 4k;

                # allow configuring custom ssl ciphers
                ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
                ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

                # In case of errors try the next upstream server before returning an error
                proxy_next_upstream                     error timeout invalid_header http_502 http_503 http_504;

                upstream default-ui-80 {
                    sticky hash=sha1 name=route  httponly;
                    server 10.128.2.104:4000 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=0;
                    server 10.128.4.37:4000 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=0;
                }

                server {
                    server_name app.com;
                    listen [::]:80;
                    listen 442  ssl http2;
                    # PEM sha: a51bd3f56b3ec447945f1f92f0ad140bb8134d11
                    ssl_certificate                         /ingress-controller/ssl/default-linker-secret.pem;
                    ssl_certificate_key                     /ingress-controller/ssl/default-linker-secret.pem;

                    more_set_headers                        "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains; preload";
                    location / {
                        set $proxy_upstream_name "default-ui-80";

                        port_in_redirect off;

                        # enforce ssl on server side
                        if ($scheme = http) {
                            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
                        }

                        client_max_body_size                    "1024m";

                        proxy_set_header Host                   $host;

                        # Pass Real IP
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;

                        # Allow websocket connections
                        proxy_set_header                        Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header                        Connection        $connection_upgrade;

                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;

                        # mitigate HTTPoxy Vulnerability
                        # https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-the-httpoxy-vulnerability-with-nginx/
                        proxy_set_header Proxy                  "";

                        # Custom headers

                        proxy_connect_timeout                   5s;
                        proxy_send_timeout                      3600s;
                        proxy_read_timeout                      3600s;

                        proxy_redirect                          off;
                        proxy_buffering                         off;
                        proxy_buffer_size                       "4k";

                        proxy_http_version                      1.1;
                        proxy_pass http://default-ui-80;
                    }
                }

            }
```

ingress controller

---

```
            apiVersion: v1
            kind: ReplicationController
            metadata:
            name: nginx-ingress-controller
            labels:
                k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
            spec:
            replicas: 1
            selector:
                k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
            template:
                metadata:
                labels:
                    k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
                    name: nginx-ingress-lb
                spec:
                terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
                containers:
                - image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.2
                    name: nginx-ingress-lb
                    imagePullPolicy: Always
                    readinessProbe:
                    httpGet:
                        path: /healthz
                        port: 10254
                        scheme: HTTP
                    livenessProbe:
                    httpGet:
                        path: /healthz
                        port: 10254
                        scheme: HTTP
                    initialDelaySeconds: 10
                    timeoutSeconds: 1
                    # use downward API
                    env:
                    - name: POD_NAME
                        valueFrom:
                        fieldRef:
                            fieldPath: metadata.name
                    - name: POD_NAMESPACE
                        valueFrom:
                        fieldRef:
                            fieldPath: metadata.namespace
                    ports:
                    - containerPort: 80
                    hostPort: 80
                    - containerPort: 443
                    hostPort: 443

                    args:
                    - /nginx-ingress-controller
                    - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
                    - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-sticky-session
                    - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-settings-configmap
                    - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-configmaps
                    - --v=2
```

ingress

```
            apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
            kind: Ingress
            metadata:
            name: foo-prod
            annotations:
                kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
                kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
                ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
                ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
                ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
                nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "1024m"
            spec:
            tls:
            - hosts:
                - foo.io
                secretName: foo-secret
            rules:
            - host: foo.io
                http:
                paths:
                - backend:
                    serviceName: foo.io
                    servicePort: 80
```

service

```
            apiVersion: v1
            kind: Service
            metadata:
            name: foo-prod-nginx
            spec:
            type: LoadBalancer
            ports:
            - port: 80
                name: http
            - port: 443
                name: https
            selector:
                app: nginx-ingress-controller
```

Comment: can you give more details on the setup and how are you using Kubernetes?

Comment: @Buchi I have updated my question, can you please take a look. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service.type=LoadBalancer allocates a public IP per k8s service, which is not how ingress works. You should expose your service as nodeport, and let ingress route traffic to it. [example here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/controllers/gce/ingress-app.yaml)

Also, if you are going to use nginx as ingress controller, you should use endpoint instead of service. [Here is why](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/controllers/nginx#why-endpoints-and-not-services)

Comment: thank you, I will try it as soon this morning at the office. and get back to you. we need to solve this problem asap..

Comment: sorry for late reply, after testing and other releases, this seemed to work, changed my service.Type=NodePort :) thank you!